# 2 kind of user Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

This is really a noob question but I've search a lot and didn't find nothing for my solution.

A have a application with 2 kind of user. Customer and Contractor. I try with devise to build both and that work I can sign in contractor and same with customer all is good in the db etc. But some things don't work.

First I can't add company name in the sign in form for the contractor(I already did that a lot but know don't work) I make the migration etc but can't show the in the sign in form. I have no error just no show.

Finally I try to make the customer build the project and have his Id with the

```
current_cutomer.projects.build(project_params)
```

and I get a error about argument etc.

Sry for my english

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

before_action :find_project, only: [:show, :quote, :edit, :update]
before_action :authenticate_cus!, except: [:index, :show]

def home
end

def index
 @projects = Project.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

def quote
end

def new
 @project = current_customer.projects.create
end

def create
 @project = current_customer.projects.create(project_params)


 if @project.save
  redirect_to @project
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end

def edit
end

def update
 if @project.update(project_params)
  redirect_to @project
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

private

def project_params
 params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :date, :budget,  :category_id, :location, :image)
end

 def find_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160305071807) do

create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "namespace"
 t.text     "body"
 t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
 t.string   "resource_type", null: false
 t.string   "author_type"
 t.integer  "author_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
add_index "active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
add_index "active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"

create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end

add_index "admin_users", ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "admin_users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "contractors", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
 t.string   "company_name"
end

add_index "contractors", ["email"], name: "index_contractors_on_email", unique: true
add_index "contractors", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_contractors_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end

add_index "customers", ["email"], name: "index_customers_on_email", unique: true
add_index "customers", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_customers_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.text     "description"
 t.integer  "budget"
 t.date     "date"
 t.string   "location"
 t.integer  "category_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
 t.string   "image_file_name"
 t.string   "image_content_type"
 t.integer  "image_file_size"
 t.datetime "image_updated_at"
 t.integer  "customer_id"
end

 add_index "projects", ["category_id"], name: "index_projects_on_category_id"
 add_index "projects", ["customer_id"], name: "index_projects_on_customer_id"

end
```

form for the contractor

```
 <h2>Sign up</h2>

 <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <h1>New Contractor</h1>
 <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :company_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "contractors/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: The best answer here is don't use two user classes - Devise is not built to support this. Use roles.

Comment: So just one user and give him 2 role ? Sorry I'm new to rails and programming.

Comment: In addition to @max answer, you may want to take a look at [the explanation in the devise's wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role)

Comment: @Emanuel Quimper – What's the error message?

Comment: So I decided to make 2 role. And I add customer_id(customer) and company_name(contractor) to user. You think I'm in the good way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did two user model with devise and in the application controller I wrote

```
devise_group :user, contains: [:customer, :company]
```

Now I can use

```
@project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
```

Everything Is ok and just need to give the permissions.